# Django secure user to local system directory mapping

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-views

I have a problem where I have to securely let logged in users access the local directory content from a specified path. */DjangoApp/media/user1*  i.e., when user1 is logged in, they should be able to access content only from */DjangoApp/media/user1*

My current View is:

```
def get_absolute_pathname(pathname='', safe=True):
if not pathname:
    return os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, 'index')
if safe and '..' in pathname.split(os.path.sep):
    return get_absolute_pathname(pathname='')
return os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, pathname)       


@login_required
def retrieve_path(request, document_root,  pathname=''):
pathname = None
if request.user.is_authenticated():
  pathname = request.user.get_username()
  abs_pathname = get_absolute_pathname(pathname)
  url = document_root
  response = HttpResponseRedirect(url)
  return response
```

Current URL is:

```
    url(regex  = r'^%s(?P<path>.*)$' % settings.STATIC_URL[1:], 
view   = 'django.views.static.serve', 
kwargs = { 'document_root': '/home/www/abc/DjangoProject/media/',
          'show_indexes' : True}),
     url(r'^user1/(?P<pathname>.*)$', 'logd.views.retrieve_path', {
        'document_root': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/DjangoApp/static/user1',
    }),     
     url(r'^user2/(?P<pathname>.*)$', 'logd.views.retrieve_path', {
        'document_root': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/DjangoApp/static/user2',
    }),
     url(r'^user3/(?P<pathname>.*)$', 'logd.views.retrieve_path', {
        'document_root': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/DjangoApp/static/user3',
    }),
     url(r'^user4/(?P<pathname>.*)$', 'logd.views.retrieve_path', {
        'document_root': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/DjangoApp/static/user4',
    }),
```

I was able to access http://127.0.0.1:8000/DjangoApp/static/ directly from the url. But I want to restrict access.

What am I doing wrong and how to make access authenticated and only restricted to a fixed path?

Thank you

Comment: Please refer this question so will have some idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28007770/how-to-to-make-a-file-private-by-securing-the-url-that-only-authenticated-users/28008035#28008035

Comment: @RajaSimon My implementation is a similar one. But as you mentioned in the comment, any logged in user can access all the data by changing the url. i.e., by changing user1 to user2. Is there a way to restrict access of user1 to only directory named user1.

Comment: wait a minute  i ll update ..

Comment: I updated my answer with more secure file serve... Only logged in user can access their files... Please take look and give credits ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Secure media file not to serve by anonymous user better url protection...

using @`login_required` and `def protected_serve(request, path, document_root=None):` you can secure it..

For more info `How to to make a file private by securing the url that only authenticated users can see`