# Django - protect files from downloading by typing their exact url

Tags: django, download

I have an app which server uploading/downloading files. It has users with different privileges, e.g. some users can download only certain files.

The problem is, if someone manages to type the exact URL of the file (e. g. localhost:8000/data/somefile.txt), they even do not need to be logged in and can see/download the file anyway.

Is there any way how to prevent this?

Comment: Yeah.. This is huge topic. I made the answer few months back. Can you look my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/28008035/3762142

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to to make a file private by securing the url that only authenticated users can see](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28007770/how-to-to-make-a-file-private-by-securing-the-url-that-only-authenticated-users)

Comment: It is sad that Django probably cannot handle this any better. It is working, though. Thank you.

Comment: Are you following my method ? or ?

Comment: Yeah, right now i am getting MultipleObjectsReturned exception thrown from your function, but I believe I can handle it.