# Django lock media url with login

Tags: django, authentication, media

I am writing a django website and using the media url function and login logout function.
Currently, all the users with and without login can view the media via 
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/image1.jpg`
but what I want is that if the user is not login, they cannot view the pictures in the media with hardcoding the URL. I dont know if django can do this function because I cannot find related question in the internet.

Comment: Have you tried to use `@login_required` decorator on the media? This should restrict access to only logged in users.

Comment: yes I have used @login_required decorator in the views.py. but what if someone just simply type the url to view the pictures? Or can you give more steps for that? I am new in Django and thanks.

Comment: try this solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/28008035/6328225

Comment: hmm... I still have some question on that coz I am newbie...
1. What should the code be placed at? which .py file?
2. why do I need such function? as the user hardcoding the url should trigger no function I think?
Please correct me if I am wrong. I am so appreciate you guys quick responses